# How Can I Get A Div to Function Just Like a Button with Depress Action

Tags: html, css, button

Good afternoon folks! I'm been trying to get my **Div to function like a button** **and depress**, and I'm almost there. I keep running into small little issues. Ok, to describe, the structure of my web app is based on CSS-grid technology, and every div fits neatly into it's own space on the grid. **On row 2, in column 2** I'm trying to have that div perform as a button and be depressed via click. I got the code to lineup that button perfectly, but now I **need to get it to depress in that same area too**. How do I do that? I found an example at this link, http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/r39vae5b/, and tried to **previously** use (per their example) absolute and relative positioning previously for the button's div container, but then it threw everything out of whack. Is my goal possible to achieve? Or does it have to be coded differently to achieve that result? Thanks in advance for your help!

[image: Screenshot]

Here is my html code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title> </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Wikipedia Viewer 2.css"  />
</head>
<body>

<div class="Main">
<h1>Wikepedia Viewer App</h1>
    <div class= grid-container>
        <div class="hold-everything">   

            <div class="button-1"><a href="#">Get Random Article</a>
            </div>

            <div class="input" id="searchTerm">
            <input type= "text" id="enter" placeholder="Enter text....">
            <!-- 
            <input class="form-control" id="searchTerm"
            <button id ="search" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            -->

            </div>

            <div class="button">
                Search
                <!--<button id ="search" type="button" class="btn btn-primary"></button>-->
            </div>

            <!-- 

            -->

            <div class="social-media">
                <!--
                <div>Facebook</div>
                <div>Twitter</div>
                <div>LinkedIn</div>
                <div>Email</div>
                -->
                social-media
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
<script src="Wikipedia Viewer.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS code:

```
.Main{
  display: grid;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: 5px 10px 0 10px;
}

h1{
    text-align: center;
}




.grid-container{
    background-image: url("https://s13.postimg.org/xxhvs5yw7/Explore.jpg");
    background-size: cover;   
    background-position: center;
    width:650px;
    height:488px;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 25px;
    align-content: center;
    border: 1px solid green;
    font-size: large;
    line-height: 3.5em;
}

.hold-everything{
    margin-top: 160px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 460px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    align-content: center;
    /*border: 1px solid green;*/

    display: grid;

    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr ;
    grid-template-rows: 85px 85px 85px ;

    grid-template-areas: 
        "button-1 button-1 button-1 button-1"
        "enter  enter  enter  button"
        "social-media social-media social-media social-media";
}

    a{
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .button-1{
        grid-area: button-1;
        text-align: center;
    }

    #enter {
        grid-area: enter;
        width: 350px;
        height: 63px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        /* used individual styling outside of grid-template styling to achieve same effect */
    }

    .button{
        grid-area: button;
    }

    .social-media {
        grid-area: social-media;
    }





.button-1,
.social-media,
#enter

{
  background-color: #999;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 150%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.button{
  background-color: #999;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 150%;
  border: 1px solid black;  
}

/*
.btn.btn-primary{
    width: 110px;
    height: 63px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
*/


.button {

    background: #eee;
    color: #000;

}

.button:hover {
    cursor: hand;
    cursor: pointer;

}

a.divLink {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}


//Below is some code I found at .....I want to (and is trying to) integrate/manipulate this into my code, and have my button perform like that

/* 
div {position:absolute; height:63px;}
*/
.button {
  font-family: OpenSans;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #00FF7C;
  border: 1px solid #00FF7C;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px #00823F;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
}
.button:active {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #00823F;
  bottom:-4px;
}

/*

div {position:relative; height:20px;}
#startBtn {
  font-family: OpenSans;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #00FF7C;
  border: 1px solid #00FF7C;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px #00823F;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
}

#startBtn:active {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #00823F;
  bottom:-4px;
}

*/
```

Comment: Why don't you just use a button instead?

Comment: @Huangism, a button wont work - well it previously wasn't working for me. Because I would want a button to fill the exact grid space that is delegated for it, which is `1fr` via the `grid-template`. I was having problems with that previously, that's why I chose a different approach.

Comment: did you have the button inside of the div? I meant replace the div with button

Comment: @Huangism, I think I may have tried both, I've lost track lol! If I replace the div with a button...? But then how will the button behave like a div? Do you mean via html or via css? Here is another way I tried to code it (aesthetically speaking).....[https://codepen.io/IDCoder/pen/rpdBQJ]

Comment: @cpdebwoy in html, use button tag instead of div tag for your button, since you want it to behave like a button. button comes with some default css which you can easily override

Comment: @Huangism, hmm....let me quickly try that!

Comment: @Huangism, I just tried that, and it didn't work.

Comment: put that code on here and let see what is not working

Comment: @Huangism, I temporarily took out my `div` code of `<div class="button-2">
    <a href="#">search</a> 
   </div>` and replaced it with this: `<button id ="search" type="button" class="btn btn-primary"></button>` and changed the CSS to match the button class and I got this [https://codepen.io/IDCoder/pen/rpdBQJ]

Comment: You can't use `.` for the btn, rename it to something else instead of `btn.btn-primary`

Comment: @Huangism, hmmm? I wonder why the `.btn btn-primary` class name wasn't working? I changed the class to `.hit-it`, like this: `<button id ="search" type="button" class="hit-it"></button>` and then added a `width` styling to it via css, and it works!! Thanks!!...see here: [https://codepen.io/IDCoder/pen/rpdBQJ] Now how can I get it to have the look of physically depressing?

Comment: The part that did not work is in `grid-template-areas` you had `btn.btn-primary` the `grid-area` name cannot contain a dot, the actual css class had nothing to do with it, you just had to rename the grid-area property

Comment: @Huangism, oh! I see, so the dot doesn't work in `grid-template-areas`!! I was wondering about that, but noone will till you that...well except you! Haha.....can you give this question/post an upvote, because this is a great reference for others as well plus I need to get my reputation up!

Comment: I will post an answer explaining this. If you read the documentation for grid-template-areas, the dot represents an empty column

Comment: Now how can I get that button to depress in that space like this: [http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/r39vae5b/], I'm scared that code might mess everything up lol....I want to find out how to implement this line of code here: `div {position:absolute; height:20px;}`

Comment: There are many ways to create the depression effect, I suggest you ask that in a different question, this line of comments are getting too long. It's the active state `:active` in that fiddle. I suggest you play around it so you will learn better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use a div and make it behave like a button. Simply use a button instead.

For the pen in the comment https://codepen.io/IDCoder/pen/rpdBQJ this did not work because in `grid-template-areas` you had

```
grid-template-areas: 
    "button-1 button-1 button-1 button-1"
    "enter  enter  enter  btn.btn-primary"
    "social-media social-media social-media social-media";
```

the dot for this rule represents an empty column and way you used it in invalid, making it not work at all. If you change that `grid-area` something else without the dot, it will work properly